# How to identify '\t' in a file?

Tags: java

I'm using this code to read a line of text from a file :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile.txt"));
String line = br.readLine();
```

If the line contains tabs : (\t) then this character is not read correctly. It just appears as an empty space. How can I determine if a tab character is contained in the line of text currently being read ?

Comment: The text is not being read char by char, but rather line by line, so `"How can I determine if a tab character is the current character being read ?"` doesn't make sense to me. You of course can see if a line contains a certain char or String using String methods such as `contains(...)` or `indexOf(...)`.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels THanks, ive updated my question. The text file contains \t characters but when I output the characters in the read String, it appears empty, ie the \t is not being read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The text file contains \t characters but when I output the characters in the read String, it appears empty, ie the \t is not being read.

My first reaction would be that this is the fault of whatever it is that is displaying the output.  Try redirecting the output to a file and viewing it with a tool that you KNOW will show any TAB characters if they are there.  (For example, the `od` utility if you are using UNIX / Linux.)  And check the input file too.

> How can I determine if a tab character is contained in the line of text currently being read ?

```
    for (char ch : line.toCharArray()) {
        if (ch == '\t') {
            System.err.println("BINGO!!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you determine it is an empty space, by printing out the string, then you are seeing the interpretation of the tab-character by the terminal you are using.  Most terminal drivers consider the tab character (ASCII 9) to mean "jump to a column being a multiple of 8" simulating the behavior of old typewriters.

Consider looking at `charAt(...)` for each character in the string and look for the value 9 instead.

Answer (score 0):

As *Hovercraft Full Of Eels* just said, you're reading a whole line, not char by char.

Anyways, you can check if its a tab-whitespace character by something like if `(String.charAt(pos) == '\t') { do stuff with it }`